# Reply.fill() - insufficient data when fetching JSON_ARRAY() data from Db2 Luw table

Tags: json, db2

I'm using Db2 LUW v11.5.5.1 as available from [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/db2/tags) with this schema:

```sql
create table t (i int, j int);
insert into t values (1, 2);
```

When I run this statement from DBeaver:

```sql
select json_array(i, j)
from t;
```

Then I'm getting this error:

> SQL Error [08001]: [jcc][t4][2030][11211][4.29.24] A communication error occurred during operations on the connection's underlying socket, socket input stream,
> or socket output stream.  Error location: Reply.fill() - insufficient data (-1).  Message: Insufficient data. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08001

This works:

```sql
select json_array(1, 2)
from t;
```

Is this a known bug on the server / in the JDBC driver (I've tried all driver versions between 11.5.0.0, 11.5.4.0, 11.5.5.0, 11.5.6.0 from [maven central](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.ibm.db2/jcc))? Are there workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Workaround for single value arrays

A workaround that works for single value arrays is this:

```sql
select json_array((select i from sysibm.dual))
from t;
```

Unfortunately, that workaround doesn't work for more than one such value. Both of these fail with the same error ([as documented, only a single subquery is allowed](https://www.ibm.com/support/producthub/db2/docs/content/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0070411.html)):

```sql
select json_array((select i from sysibm.dual), j)
from t;

select json_array((select i from sysibm.dual), (select j from sysibm.dual))
from t;
```

> SQL Error [42601]: An unexpected token "," was found following "i from sysibm.dual)".  Expected tokens may include:  "=".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.29.24

#### Workaround for multi value arrays without joins

But incredibly, this works!

```sql
select (select json_array(i, j) from sysibm.dual)
from t;
```

#### Workaround for queries with joins

But the above workaround fails again as soon as there's a join:

```sql
create table t (i int, j int);
create table u (i int, j int);
insert into t values (1, 2);
insert into u values (1, 2);

-- And then, this fails again:
select (select json_array(t.i, u.j) from sysibm.dual)
from t join u on t.i = u.i
```

But I shall not give up. It is possible to completely re-invent the seemingly trivial `JSON_ARRAY()` function using `JSON_QUERY()` and `JSON_OBJECT()`.

Not saying you should, but you definitely could.

```sql
select json_query(
  json_object(key 'k' value t.i, key 'k' value u.j), 
  '$.*' with unconditional array wrapper
)
from t join u on t.i = u.i
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error, and found out that JSON_ARRAY expects a single column to be returned when using SELECT statement inside of it.

If you need to build json array out of SELECT result, you need to ensure that it returns multiple rows with single column each.
If desired values are in two columns of a single result row, you can use union all to get them in two separate result rows.

E.g instead of:

```
select json_array((select i from sysibm.dual), (select j from sysibm.dual))
from t;
```

You should try

```
select json_array(select i from sysibm.dual union all select j from sysibm.dual) 
from t;
```

This works also for joined tables, e.g.:

```
select json_array(select t.i from sysibm.dual union all select u.j from sysibm.dual) 
from t join u on t.i = u.i
```

or by creating a single column TABLE:

```
select json_array(select * from TABLE(VALUES(t.i),(u.j)))
from t join u on t.i = u.i
```

Comment: Ah yes, of course. That's the standard SQL `<json array constructor by query>`, which can be used as a workaround for the problems [in my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68230222/521799). [In my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68228063/521799), though, I wanted to use the `<json array constructor by enumeration>`. Being unable to use the latter with scalar subqueries seems like quite the arbitrary and unnecessary limitation. But your approach might definitely help as a workaround

Comment: Apparently enumeration works only for fixed values, not for an array of references to column values. Using a subquery with `TABLE VALUES` (e.g. `select * from TABLE(VALUES(t.i),(u.j))`) is as close to enumeration as it gets :)

I also found out that the error caused by using the "intuitive" enumeration approach was not properly supported in my db2 version, and after couple of attempts it caused  db to crash - so please test carefully :)

Comment: Yes, I'm avoiding JSON in Db2 for now :-/

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a defect in Db2-LUW server at v11.5.5.1 (i.e not related to jdbc driver).

Seems to be fixed in Db2-LUW v11.5.6.0.

Comment: It's already available https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/db2/tags, but when I use that version, I get this kind of error already when trying to connect... Will have to investigate further